# not only... but also (but also - together)

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, subject-verb-inversion, parallelism

I know that parallelism is a maxim when it comes to talking about this matter, my question is:

Not only do I like chocolate, but I also like coffee. (this is correct)
Not only do I like chocolate, but also I like coffee. (is there any problem with this one?)

I think is OK but I have just had a discussion with a colleague.

Comment: It's fine. And so is _but I like coffee also_. You can also use _too_ at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of structural parallelism, you can think of "Not only ... but also ..." constructions as presenting X and Y values in parallel. English is quite flexible in letting speakers and writers set up such constructions to suit their preferences while still maintaining strict parallelism. For example, you might say

> Not only do X, but also Y,

where X = "I like chocolate" and Y = "I like coffee". Or you might say

> I not only X, but also Y,

where X = "like chocolate" and Y = "like coffee". Or you might say

> I like not only X, but also Y,

where X = "chocolate" and Y = "coffee".

And those are just the forms that satisfy a fairly strict notion of parallelism. Your first example, which amounts to saying

> Not only do I X, but I also Y,

where X = "like chocolate" and Y = "like coffee", is somewhat less compact (and more awkward) than the first three examples above, because it has a lengthier buildup to the parallel elements X and Y than they do. Nevertheless, it is syntactically coherent and quite common in both speech and writing.

The more logically problematic forms arise in situations where the X and Y elements achieve true parallelism only with the listener's or reader's help. For example,

> Not only do I like X, but also Y,

where X = "chocolate" and Y = "coffee" is logically incomplete to the extent that it requires the listener or reader to interpolate the missing wording to complete the parallel match:

> Not only do I like X, but also [I like] Y.

Again, this is the sort of structural inconsistency that readers and listeners sort through and reconcile multiple times every day without (in most cases) even being aware that they are doing it. Nevertheless, in dealing with written instances of this sort, an editor might reasonably ask, "Who should be responsible for identifying the intended parallel structure here—the reader or the writer?" On grounds of efficiency alone—one writer versus (potentially) many readers—it seems to me that the writer should accept that responsibility.

---

In the examples I've discussed so far, the sentence's parallel X and Y elements are quite simple. But some sentences that use "not only ... but also ..." constructions are longer and more complex, and untangling them is a burden that no conscientious writer should leave to the reader. Consider this example, which I encountered during my days as an editor for a computer magazine:

> Trenthuite is convinced that Jascha is not only guilty of authoring and spreading the Sassy worm, but also that he acted with malicious intent.

Applying the X and Y variable system to the sentence yields this wording:

> Trenthuite is convinced that Jascha is not only X, but also Y,

where X = "guilty of authoring and spreading the Sassy worm" and Y = "that he acted with malicious intent". The attempted parallelism here is ghastly. To make sense of the sentence, interested readers must reconstruct it. This entails moving the "not only" marker forward in the sentence:

> Trenthuite is convinced not only X, but also Y,

where X = "that Jascha is guilty of authoring and spreading the Sassy worm" and Y = "that he acted with malicious intent". That is, in reconstituted form:

> Trenthuite is convinced not only that Jascha is guilty of authoring and spreading the Sassy worm, but also that he acted with malicious intent.

Alternatively, we could move the "not only" marker to the beginning of the sentence:

> Not only is Trenthuite convinced that Jascha is guilty of authoring and spreading the Sassy worm, but also he believes that Jascha acted with malicious intent.

In both revisions, the intended parallelism is immediately clear, so readers can easily grasp the intended meaning and move on.